# JNA : Get value from a pointer to a pointer to a structure

Tags: java, pointers, jna

I'm getting trouble with JNA about pointer to pointer problem.

Example structure:

```
typedef struct _A {
    unsigned int num;
    struct _A *next;
} A, *PA;
```

C method:

```
void test(PA *a) {
    PA current = (PA) malloc(sizeof(A));
    current->num = 123321;

    PA next = (PA) malloc(sizeof(A));
    next->num = 456;
    current->next = next;

    *a = current;
}
```

A simple test in C:

```
int main() {
    PA a = NULL;
    test(&a);

    printf("%d\n", a->num);
    printf("%d", a->next->num);
}
```

JNA code

```
public interface DLLLibrary extends Library {
    ......

    void test(PointerByReference a);
}

public class A extends Structure {
    public int num;
    public ByReference next;
    public A() {
        super();
    }
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("num", "next");
    }

    public A(Pointer peer) {
        super(peer);
    }
    public static class ByReference extends A implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public static class ByValue extends A implements Structure.ByValue { }
}
```

Finally , I am trying to get the structure fields that was updated in C, but get "Invalid memory access"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
    DLLLibrary.INSTANCE.test(pointer);

    assert pointer.getValue().getInt(0) == 123321; //this works
    A a = new A(pointer.getValue());
    //assert a.next.num == 456;  //excepted action
    a.read(); //java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
}
```

Any mistakes in my steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an "Invalid memory access" error you should start looking at when native memory allocations are done.  Usually the API documents that (and tells you how to free it) and when not, you know it's your responsibility.  In this case you can see in the C code you've posted, the allocation is done inside the test method:

```
PA current = (PA) malloc(sizeof(A));
```

and

```
PA next = (PA) malloc(sizeof(A));
```

The problem here is that the Java side doesn't know about that allocation so you have to do it manually.

Your mapping of the function using a `PointerByReference` looks fine.  While you can use `getInt(0)` on the return, you'd probably be better off at this point just instantiating the `A` structure from the returned pointer as you've done:

```
A a = new A(pointer.getValue());
```

Then `a.num` should be your expected 123321.  Then you have to take the returned pointer (to the native-allocated link) and use that to create another Java-side structure:

```
A b = new A(a.next);
```

(You may want to just use a `Pointer` in the structure to make that part easy. If you use `ByReference` or `A.ByReference` then use `getPointer()` at this part.)

At this point, I believe `b.num` should give you 456.

Comment: Hey @Daniel Widdis, Really thank you for helping me, the reason you pointed out is reasonable, but  the fix steps same not work. 1. When i change the mapping to ``` void test(A a)```  , A.num is pointed to random number, and the ```next``` field get ```null```.

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure why it's not working. The native code is allocating the memory but the Java side isn't seeing it. There are a few ways to make that work. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: You can see the changed java code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/Camork/8e0d66b36bb9e3cfb04a819a31bf69f0)

Comment: Thanks. OK, this is a really unusual API.  I guess I was wrong to suggest sending a structure, thinking it would populate that.  In fact you do have to send a bare pointer (by reference) because the native code does the allocation.  So I suppose your earlier code was right for the pointer / getInt part.  And the new A() part was proably good too.  I think you need to do another new A() on the pointer retrieved from Next.  Let me totally rewrite my answer....

Comment: OK, answer updated based on rereading everything.  It's really unusual for the API to allocate memory like that, rather than taking memory already allocated and passed in its arguments.   How is the memory released later?

Comment: You are right, the problem is the ```next``` field got invalid memory access , and I do nothing about memory release since I even have no chance to read it.

Comment: That works, thank you. I need to change the ```ByReference``` field to ```Pointer``` to avoid read a invalid memory, that because i didn't set the value of ```next->next``` to ```NULL``` in C.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Note that every time you call `test()` the native code is allocating memory, that is not being released.  I assume you're just extracting a portion of an API for help here, but for completeness you should find where the API expects you to release that memory allocated for A, otherwise you have a memory leak.